# How to use process.env.PORT in reactjs to fetch data in production build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got this code, where I am trying to fetch the data from database and it works on local host:

```
async function getLikedAnimations(username) { 
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/animation-list/?username=${username}`); 
    const json = await res.json();
    const likedAnimations = json.animationList;

    return likedAnimations;
}
```

How can I replace localhost with **process.env.PORT** or is there any other way, I tried this:

```
async function getLikedAnimations(username) { 
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PORT}/animation-list/?username=${username}`); 
    const json = await res.json();
    const likedAnimations = json.animationList;

    return likedAnimations;
}
```

And it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set your PORT - in this case the output would be something like `8080/animation-list/?username=${username}`. I believe it should be something like

```
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/${process.env.PORT}/animation-list/?username=${username}`);
```